# How to get relative file path on Sharepoint for copying files

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint, onedrive

I have a small script to save files with a date and time as a copy into an archive folder. This works perfectly on a regular drive, but now the files got moved to a OneDrive Sharepoint and I get an error "file not found". Is there a relative file path on Sharepoint? The dp0 does not seem to work. Thank you!

```
@ECHO OFF
set day=%date:~0,2%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set year=%date:~6%

SET DAT=%DATE:~6%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%
Set ZEIT=%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%

copy /Y %~dp0\MYFILE.xlsx %~dp0\Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_MYFILE.xlsx
copy /Y %~dp0\MYFILE1.xlsx %~dp0\Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_MYFILE1.xlsx
copy /Y %~dp0\MYFILE2.xlsx %~dp0\Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_MYFILE2.xlsx

pause
```

Comment: Why have you defined three variables then completely ignored them? either use `SET "DAT=%year%%month%%day%"` or remove lines 2, 3, and 4. Also ```%~dp0\``` should be ```%~dp0```, as it already ends with a trailing backwards slash! I would assume also that if you really do want spaces in your resultant file names then you're going to have to enclose those names with doublequotes. e.g. ```%~dp0\Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_ MYFILE2.xlsx``` => ```"%~dp0Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_ MYFILE2.xlsx"```.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The empty space was a mistake in my post. The dp0 works with the Backslash on a drive, but not und Sharepoint, taking it out does not make a difference.

Comment: I'm curious, what `echo %~f0` would tell when executed from a sharepoint?

Comment: Given the fact that your script is obviously located in the OneDrive Sharepoint too, why not just insert this at line `2`, `PushD "%~dp0\." 2>NUL`. Then you can replace your bottom three lines with, `Copy /Y "MYFILE.xlsx" "Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_MYFILE.xlsx"`, `Copy /Y "MYFILE1.xlsx" "Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_MYFILE1.xlsx"`, and `Copy /Y "MYFILE2.xlsx" "Archiv\%DAT%_%ZEIT%_MYFILE2.xlsx"`.

Comment: @compo Thank you! Your suggestion works like a charm! Maybe add it as an answer, then I will check mark it.

Comment: @Stephan I tested your suggestion, it shows the path of the file on the OneDrive directory, but to be clear, it shows a local path on the client, not on the server.

Comment: `it shows a local path on the client, not on the server` - I cannot test it, but that's quite what I have expected - a local path. Note that @Compo's suggestion will copy from that local path, not from the server (they synchronize, but you have no knowledge if you have the most recent version already synced)

Comment: @Stephan, thanks for the comment. That is what I am expecting too. However, it should normally not be a problem. We still have the versioning of the Sharepoint as a fall back, should this "manual" documentation fail.